# Confused with object-c memory management

Tags: objective-c

Below is a code snippet from a book. Why can `serialNumber` still be set to new value after `[serialNumber release];`?

```
 - (void)setSerialNumber:(NSString *)newSerialNumber
{
NSString *newValue;
// Is it a mutable string?
if ([newSerialNumber isKindOfClass:[NSMutableString class]])
// I need to copy it
newValue = [newSerialNumber copy];
else
// It is sufficient to retain it
newValue = [newSerialNumber retain];
[serialNumber release];
serialNumber = newValue;
}
```

Comment: release just decrease refCount to -1. It doesn't assume that variable will deallocated. Read [Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/)

Comment: `copy` is equivalent to `retain` for immutable strings — no need for this `if`.

Comment: The best solution would be to declare `@property(copy) NSString*serialNumber;`, `@synthesize` that, and be done with it.  No reason to write any of this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release message decrement the retainCount by 1. It's just like calling any other function.
When you assign a pointer variable a new value you are relocating the pointer (not the object you just used in the previous statement) to a different object.

Comment: thanks. I just mix-up with the meaning of "release" in programming language and human language. :-)

Comment: There is no garbage collector when using manual retain/release.

Comment: Changed the part about garbage collector since it didn't relate to the question.

Answer (score 2):

`newValue` and `serialNumber` are just **pointers** to Objective-C objects. When you send messages like `release` or `retain`, they are sent to the actual objects that the pointers point to.

`[serialNumber release]` sends the `release` method to the object that `serialNumber` points to. Then, `serialNumber = newValue` assigns the same value as the `newValue` pointer to `serialNumber`. At that point, the value of the `newValue` pointer is a mutable string (either the same value as `newSerialNumber` or a copy of it), which has been retained, since it was either copied or retained, so everything is peachy.